# Can NRF24L01 use IEEE 802.15.4 and 6LoWPAN protocol?

Tags: rf, 802.15.4

I'm new to embedded systems and wireless sensor networks. I want to make a wireless sensor network which is based on 6LoWPAN protocol for monitoring application. As stated on Wikipedia, 6LoWPAN runs over IEEE 802.15.4 protocol. What I want to know are:

1. Is it possible to use [NRF24L01](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01) transceiver for IEEE 802.15.4 protocol? If it is possible, how can I achieve it?
2. If NRF24L01 can be used for 802.15.4, can I use for 6LoWPAN protocol?

By the way, I plan to use STM32 for the nodes and Raspberry Pi 2 for the gateway.

Comment: What does the manufacturer say?

Comment: It does not say anything about 802.15.4. But the datasheet states that it operates at 2.4 GHz and 250 kbps, looks the same as 802.15.4

Comment: @Andyaka that the part is not recommended for new designs, among other things - they don't mention any protocol, so I guess the specification of the IEEE 802.15.4 must be checked and compared with the datasheet to see if the NRF24L01 can fulfil all the requirements...

Comment: @Arsenal The manufacturer would likely know though?

Comment: Ask Nordic. They hire applications engineers for a reason.

Comment: Given that people have emulated BLE beacons with the chip, the question isn't so far fetched at all to downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see the NRF24L01 only supports GFSK modulation, IEEE 802.15.4 requires DSSS, so it can not support 802.15.4.

The CC2520 transceiver was designed for 802.15.4. But if you want an easy life then look at using BeagleBone + CC2531 as the border router and CC2650 Sensor Tags for you nodes. There is very little work needed to get this running see:
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Cc26xx_sw_examples

For other 6LowPAN topics including cloud connectivity see:
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Contiki-6LOWPAN